# client.run getting timed out (discord.py)

Tags: client, discord.py

i am using

```
import discord
client=discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('WE have logged in')


client.run('my token goes here')
```

But the problem isnt with the script . Because a few days ago it was working fine and i could easily connect to my bot and do stuff . But today i kicked it out and added it again and from then on it doesnt work .

Heres What i did

-I added Outh2 access from the discord dev portal , by copying an url and going there 
- Copied the current token and use it 
- Authorize / add it again to my server (i know i shouldnt have done this one )

```
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 582, in _request
    break
  File "/home/soutrik/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 596, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

the error is inside the client.run statement , when i first started out i also faced this same timout error ,but i dont remember how it got solved.
I changed the name and tried after sometime and it worked , which in this case i did try but it didnt work.

Maybe i a doing something entirely different wrongly .

Answer (score 0):

Well um... You kind of need a prefix. Replace `client=discord.Client()` with `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['Prefix goes here'])`